# How could I "dry" common documentation for common methods through several C++ classes?

Tags: c++, doxygen

I'm using doxygen for documenting a C++ library.

Let's say I have several classes A, B, C, etc., which share a common set of methods `A::m1(), B::m1(), ...`etc. The methods essentially do the same thing in each class.

I want a single implementation of those common methods.

An alternative is that the classes (A, B, C, etc) inherit a common class having the common methods. However, according to my measurements, this approach means a slight sacrifice in performance when is combined with multi-inheritance. In fact some of my classes inherit other classes, so the multi-inheritance is sure.

So, in order to "factorise" the common methods I wrote them in a big macro. Something like:

```
define COMMON_METHODS() \
void m1() { ..- } \
void m2() { ... \
```

Then, in each class, I put this macro.

I'm aware that this may not be the best technique (although in performance is very good).

Now, I also want to write a single doc for the common methods and that (the doc) was managed and generated by doxygen.

Unfortunately, I can not find or conceive some way (in the context of doxygen) to write the doc once.

So I would really appreciate if someone could offer some trick or idea to let me write the documentation once.

Regards

Comment: One option:  suffer the slight performance hit in exchange for better code maintainability.

Comment: CRTP can help keep your common method implementations DRY.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using `COMMON_METHODS` to automate the creation of some methods in a bunch of classes, you might want to consider encapsulating those methods in a template instead, and use CRTP.

```
template <typename C>
class CommonMethods {
    C * me () { return static_cast<C *>(this); }
protected:
    // ... common data members can go here ...
public:
    void m1 () {
        //... use me() if needed ...
    }
    //...
};

class A : public CommonMethods<A>, //...
{
    friend class CommonMethods<A>;
    //...
};
```

This is different than all your classes inheriting from a common interface. There is no virtual interface lookup penalty with this technique.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer @jxh.

It sounds to be a perfect solution, conditioned upon doxygen be able to identify all and generate the inherited documentation; I presume yes; I'll check then. In any case, it looks a lot much better than the macro approach. Thanks again.

Now, I wonder if it would be possible to dry a common constructor. That is, suppose the common classes share a common constructor with the same implementation. There would be some way to make it through CRTP? (or another way)

Comment: The default constructor of the base class will be invoked unless the constructor of the derived object explicitly calls a different constructor.

Comment: If you set INHERIT_DOCS to yes in the doxygen config, the base class documentation will be copied.

Comment: I've been a part of day refactoring one of my classes and testing it. The approach that you suggested works pretty well, the documentation is generated and no loss of performance. So serve this note to express my sincere thanks. Best regards,